# Does Java codemodel support GenericEntity

Tags: java, jcodemodel

Does Java codemodel support GenericEntity ?

I am trying to generate a code like below using jcodemodel:

```
Object obj = new GenericEntity<List<java.lang.String>>(listStr){}
```

But I am not able do that. I used below code :

```
JType jObjType = ((JClass) jcodemodel._ref(GenericEntity.class)).narrow(jcodemodel.ref(List.class).narrow(
                jcodemodel.ref(String.class)));
JVar jvobj = jMethodResource.body().decl(jcm.ref(Object.class), "obj",  JExpr._new(jObjType).arg(.....listStr reference...));
```

The code obtained using this is as follows :
Object obj = new GenericEntity>(listStr)

But "{}" is missing.

Can anyone help me here? How do a code so that I am obtained with **{}** :

```
Object obj = new GenericEntity<List<java.lang.String>>(listStr){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method (https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel.html#anonymousClass(com.sun.codemodel.JClass)). Something like that:

```
    JClass listOfEmplType = jcodemodel.ref(List.class).narrow(jcodemodel.ref(
            Emplyee.class.getName()));
    JVar listOfEmpl = jMethodResource.body().decl(listOfEmplType, "listStr", JExpr._null());
    JClass jObjType = ((JClass) jcodemodel._ref(GenericEntity.class)).narrow(listOfEmplType);
    JVar jvobj = jMethodResource.body().decl(jcodemodel.ref(Object.class), "obj",  
            JExpr._new(jcodemodel.anonymousClass(jObjType)).arg(listOfEmpl));
```

Comment: Now support I have List of Employee object, if I code like below it is not importing Employee class(import com.Employee is not adding)


`JClass jObjType = ((JClass) jcodemodel._ref(GenericEntity.class)).narrow(jcodemodel.ref(List.class).narrow(
            jcodemodel.ref(Employee.class)));
JVar jvobj = jMethodResource.body().decl(jcodemodel.ref(Object.class), "obj",  JExpr._new(jcodemodel.anonymousClass(jObjType)).arg(JExpr.direct("listStr")));`

Any solution please?

Comment: It looks like there is some issue in JCodeModel with generic type importing. If you explicitly declare variable of List<Employee> type it fixes import problem. So why don't you accept my answer and we can discuss your further issues in comments?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I click, but missed by my bad mouse :). 
Yeah, I did what you say. It just having an used variable. Thanks a ton. You really save my few hours effort.